# Oracle: '= ANY()' vs. 'IN ()'

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

I just stumbled upon something in ORACLE SQL (not sure if it's in others), that I am curious about. I am asking here as a wiki, since it's hard to try to search symbols in google...

I just found that when checking a value against a set of values you can do

```
WHERE x = ANY (a, b, c)
```

As opposed to the usual

```
WHERE x IN (a, b, c)
```

So I'm curious, what is the reasoning for these two syntaxes? Is one **standard** and one some oddball Oracle syntax? Or are they both standard? And is there a preference of one over the other for performance reasons, or ?

Just curious what anyone can tell me about that '= ANY' syntax.

Comment: I don't know this to be true but: `= ANY ()` is the same as `IN ()`, because `IN` is really just written as a short hand for `= ANY ()`. `ANY` conversely does not have to take the `=` operator.

Comment: This is actually part of ISO SQL92 syntax. You can check on [http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt], section `8.7  <quantified comparison predicate>`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`ANY` (or its synonym `SOME`) is a syntax sugar for `EXISTS` with a simple correlation:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   x <= ANY
        (
        SELECT  y
        FROM    othertable
        )
```

is the same as:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable m
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    othertable o
        WHERE   m.x <= o.y
        )
```

With the equality condition on a not-nullable field, it becomes similar to `IN`.

All major databases, including `SQL Server`, `MySQL` and `PostgreSQL`, support this keyword.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for explaining. Out of continued curiosity, looking at your example, I would expect the "EXISTS" method to perform better, no? As with the ANY method it has to bring back all the sub rows before checking, where as the EXISTS is returning a subset to check? Really I guess this all depends on how the query parsers are optimized.

Comment: @eidylon: `ANY` returns as soon as it finds the first matching row. Is it a pure syntax sugar for `EXISTS` and is optimized in the very same way as `EXISTS`. There is one more condition, `ALL`. `ANY` returns `TRUE` on the first matching row, `ALL` returns `FALSE` on the first non-matching row.

Comment: Be careful about the assumption that EXISTS performs better; EXISTS plans, at least in Oracle, tend to require correlated subqueries, which drive to nested loop plans.  It's been my idiosyncratic experience that IN-based semi- and anti-joins, when safe (against non-null columns) scale out better than EXISTS-based semi- and anit-joins.  Doing an index probe for each row in a 10 row table is okay; doing one for a 10 million row table can be painful.

Comment: @Adam: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/17/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-oracle/

Answer (score 24):

```
IN- Equal to any member in the list
ANY- Compare value to **each** value returned by the subquery
ALL- Compare value to **EVERY** value returned by the subquery

<ANY() - less than maximum
>ANY() - more than minimum
=ANY() - equivalent to IN
>ALL() - more than the maximum
<ALL() - less than the minimum
```

eg:

**Find the employees who earn the same salary as the minimum salary for each department:**

```
SELECT last_name, salary,department_id
FROM employees
WHERE salary IN (SELECT MIN(salary)
                 FROM employees
                 GROUP BY department_id);
```

**Employees who are not IT Programmers and whose salary is less than that of any IT programmer:**

```
SELECT employee_id, last_name, salary, job_id
FROM employees
WHERE salary <ANY
                (SELECT salary
                 FROM employees
                 WHERE job_id = 'IT_PROG')
AND job_id <> 'IT_PROG';
```

**Employees whose salary is less than the salary ofall employees with a job ID of IT_PROG and whose job is not IT_PROG:**

```
SELECT employee_id,last_name, salary,job_id
FROM employees
WHERE salary <ALL
                (SELECT salary
                 FROM employees
                 WHERE job_id = 'IT_PROG')
AND job_id <> 'IT_PROG';
```

....................

Hope it helps.
-Noorin Fatima

Comment: What's the difference between `each` and `every`?

Answer (score 19):

To put it simply and quoting from O'Reilly's "Mastering Oracle SQL":

> "Using IN with a subquery is functionally equivalent to using ANY, and returns TRUE if a match is found in the set returned by the subquery."
>
> "We think you will agree that IN is more intuitive than ANY, which is why IN is almost always used in such situations."

Hope that clears up your question about ANY vs IN.

Answer (score 10):

I *believe* that what you are looking for is this:

http://download-west.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96533/opt_ops.htm#1005298
(Link found on [Eddie Awad's Blog](http://awads.net/wp/2005/08/09/any-some-and-all-in-oracle/))
To sum it up here:

> `last_name IN ('SMITH', 'KING',
>   'JONES')`
>
> is transformed into
>
> `last_name = 'SMITH' OR last_name =
>   'KING' OR last_name = 'JONES'`

while

> `salary > ANY (:first_sal,
>   :second_sal)`
>
> is transformed into
>
> `salary > :first_sal OR salary >
>   :second_sal`
>
> The optimizer transforms a condition
>   that uses the ANY or SOME operator
>   followed by a subquery into a
>   condition containing the EXISTS
>   operator and a correlated subquery

Answer (score 7):

The ANY syntax allows you to write things like

```
WHERE x > ANY(a, b, c)
```

or event

```
WHERE x > ANY(SELECT ... FROM ...)
```

Not sure whether there actually is anyone on the planet who uses ANY (and its brother ALL).

Comment: It can be useful for things like...  Select Salary from HRData where Salary > Any (Select band_upper_limit from salaryBands) Just saves doing the Select top(1) band_upper_limit from salaryBands order by band_upper_limit desc in the last sub query.

Answer (score 7):

A quick google found this http://theopensourcery.com/sqlanysomeall.htm

Any allows you to use an operator other than = , in most other respect (special cases for nulls) it acts like IN.  You can think of IN as  ANY with the = operator.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard. The [SQL 1992](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt) standard states

> 8.4  <in predicate>
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> <in predicate> ::=
>     <row value constructor>
>       [ NOT ] IN <in predicate value>
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> 2) Let RVC be the <row value constructor> and let IPV be the <in predicate value>.
>
> [...]
>
> 4) The expression
>
> ```
>   RVC IN IPV
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
>   RVC = ANY IPV
> ```

So in fact, the `<in predicate>` behaviour definition is based on the `8.7 <quantified comparison predicate>`. In Other words, Oracle correctly implements the SQL standard here

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of the linked articles points this out, but isn't it true that when looking for a match (=) the two return the same thing. However, if looking for a range of answers (>, <, etc) you cannot use "IN" and would have to use "ANY"...

I'm a newb, forgive me if I've missed something obvious...

Comment: Yes, you'd be right. When I had asked this question, I had never actually run across the ANY syntax before, it was completely new to me. So I was curious about how exactly it worked and compared to other syntaxes.

Answer (score 1):

MySql clears up ANY in it's documentation pretty well:

> The ANY keyword, which must follow a comparison operator, means
>   “return TRUE if the comparison is TRUE for ANY of the values in the
>   column that the subquery returns.” For example:

`SELECT s1 FROM t1 WHERE s1 > ANY (SELECT s1 FROM t2);`

> Suppose that there is a row in table t1 containing (10). The
>   expression is TRUE if table t2 contains (21,14,7) because there is a
>   value 7 in t2 that is less than 10. The expression is FALSE if table
>   t2 contains (20,10), or if table t2 is empty. The expression is
>   unknown (that is, NULL) if table t2 contains (NULL,NULL,NULL).

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html

Also Learning SQL by Alan Beaulieu states the following:

> Although most people prefer to use IN, using = ANY is equivalent to
>   using the IN operator.

Answer (score 0):

Why I always use `any` is because in some oracle or mssql versions IN list is limited by 1000/999 elements. While `= any ()`  is not limited by 1000.

Nobody likes their sql query crashing a web request.
So there is a practical difference.

Second reason it is the more modern form. As it correlates with expressions like `> all (...)`.

Third reason is somehow for me as non-native English speaker it appears more natural to use "any" and "all" than to use IN.