# Achieving ANY() functionality in RORacle

Tags: sql, r, oracle, roracle

I have a query I've written in SQL Developer that runs and returns what I want. I then tried to load it into R so that I can analyze the results, but I've found that my `ANY()` statements don't translate at all.

The query I've written is

```
query <- paste("SELECT * FROM DAILY_INFO t1",
   "INNER JOIN COHORTS_TABLE t2",
   "ON t1.id = t2.id",
   "WHERE t2.cohort = '2013'",
   "AND t1.level = ANY('09','10','11','12')",
   "AND t2.id2 = ANY([Placeholder for long list of numeric IDs here])",
   "ORDER BY t1.id, t1.level, t2.system_name;",
   sep=' ')
```

This query works exactly in SQLDeveloper but ROracle doesn't seem to recognize the `ANY()` statement. Is it just that the `ANY()` function is not accepted? I guess that it's solely a SQLDeveloper function...

Does anyone know how I can achieve that functionality simply in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ROracle driver doesn't properly recognize the ANY () Syntax, you could replace that with the IN () equivalent.

```
AND t1.level IN ('09','10','11','12'),
   AND t2.id2 IN ([Placeholder for long list of numeric IDs here]),
```

See the [discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298550/oracle-any-vs-in) on ANY vs IN

Comment: Great tip, hadn't thought of this. Thanks!