# sql NOT with ALL operator

Tags: sql, operators

I'm trying to use the `NOT` operator with `ALL` but does not compare as it should

I followed the following:

tablex contains for example:

```
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    6 | a    |
|    7 | b    |
|    8 | c    |
|    9 | d    |
|   10 | e    |
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

and tabley contains:

```
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    4 | a    |
|    5 | b    |
|    7 | c    |
|    8 | d    |
+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

i've used:

```
SELECT id, name FROM tablex WHERE NOT id < ALL (SELECT id FROM tabley);
```

returns:

```
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    6 | a    |
|    7 | b    |
|    8 | c    |
|    9 | d    |
|   10 | e    |
+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

the problem is that returns lower values than those of 'tabley' in some cases,
It is very logical the solution using the operator `>`, but what is this about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the `<` operator, it seems like you want to make sure that `id` is smaller than the *smallest* `id` in the subquery. So to express that in SQL:

```
SELECT id, name FROM tablex WHERE NOT id < (SELECT min(id) FROM tabley)
```

Alternately, flipping around the negation:

```
SELECT id, name FROM tablex WHERE id >= (SELECT min(id) FROM tabley)
```

Comment: ok, but one example:

<code> SELECT id, name FROM tablex WHERE NOT id < ANY (SELECT id FROM tabley); </code>

returns:
<code>
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|    8 | c    |
|    9 | d    |
|   10 | e    |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.11 sec)
</code>
why works with 'ANY' but no with 'ALL'?

Comment: @nikomaster perhaps this might help illustrate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2298576/139010

Comment: And this: _"The word `ALL`, which must follow a comparison operator, means “return `TRUE` if the comparison is `TRUE` for `ALL` of the values in the column that the subquery returns.”"_ http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/all-subqueries.html