# node-postgres: Update more than one record at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

I'm building an app in node.js using node-postgres. I don't know how to update more than one record at once. 
Here is my code:

```
var status = 20;
var id = [23,12,43];

pool.connect(function(err, client, done) 

{


if(err) 
{
      done();
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).send(json({ success: false, data: err}));
}
    client.query("UPDATE myDatabase SET status=($1) WHERE id IN($2);", [status,id]);
```

But I've got a problem - console:

> events.js:160
>         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>         ^
>
> error: invalid input syntax for integer: "23,12,43"

What can I do in that case? What kind of data use? the length of var id will be not the same every time.

Greetings, Rafał 
EDIT: I think that a change of data will work in javascript, the input must be 23,12,43, but instead is [23,12,43] but I don't know how to make that.

Comment: Are you using `node-postgres` directly or via [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise)?

Comment: I've just saw pg-promise and it's looking nice, I will definietly try that

Comment: with `pg-promise` you can format id-s in your query like this: `WHERE id = ANY($2:csv)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use `ANY`:

```
client.query("UPDATE myDatabase SET status=($1) WHERE id = ANY($2);", [status,id]);
```

This is due Postgresql itself, not the library: see [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1187290651.24679.10.camel@dogma.ljc.laika.com) and [this](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/1008)

See also this question: [Oracle: '= ANY()' vs. 'IN ()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298550/oracle-any-vs-in)